# Send message to Uber driver when requesting ride

Tags: php, uber-api

I want to be able to send a message to the Uber driver when I request a ride through the Ride API for web.

How would I go about this, I already have setup OAuth access, and can access other data as required, but I need to be able to send the driver a message when the ride is booked.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the current request endpoint to get the drivers details once a trip has been accepted: https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/api/v1-requests-current

Messaging isn't supported but you can use a sms provider like twilio/plivo to send messages to the anonymous sms # provided via the endpoint. See this example from twilio: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages